# apply function to all columns in pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

I have the following dataframe (let's call it `data`):

```
id | type | val1 | val2 |
-------------------------
1  |  A   | 10.1 | 11.0 |
1  |  B   | 10.5 | 11.2 |
2  |  A   | 10.7 | 10.9 |
2  |  B   | 10.6 | 11.1 |
3  |  A   | 10.3 | 10.5 |
3  |  B   | 10.4 | 11.3 |
```

and I want to obtain the difference between the types `A` and `B` (`A`-`B`) for each `id` for each `valX` column, i.e. I want the result to be:

```
id | val1 | val2 |
------------------
1  | -0.4 | -0.2 |
2  |  0.1 | -0.2 |
3  | -0.1 | -0.8 |
```

The only way I could get this done was to define a function:

```py
def getDelta(df, valName):
    return df[ df['type']=='A' ][valName].values[0] - df[ df['type']=='B' ][valName].values[0]
```

and apply it for each column separately:

```py
data.groupby('id').apply(getDelta,valName='val1')
```

and then merge the results to obtain what I was looking for.

Is there a more efficient way to do it? In the end I want to apply a function to a subset of columns of the grouped dataframe, but this function has to take into account the values of another column.

Comment: is it always going to be `A` and `B` per `id`? will there be duplicate `A`s or `B`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it currently is you can use `np.subtract.reduce`, assuming 'A' comes before 'B' in all cases, and there are no duplicates:

```
df.groupby("id", sort = False).agg(np.subtract.reduce).reset_index()

   id  val1  val2
0   1  -0.4  -0.2
1   2   0.1  -0.2
2   3  -0.1  -0.8
```

Comment: to make sure that 'A' comes always before 'B' I added a `df.sort_values(by=['id','type'])` before your solution. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby()` your ID column  and use `diff(-1)` on your `valX` columns. Wrapping the operation in `concat()`, will you give you your desired outcome.

```
df.set_index('id',inplace=True)
pd.concat([df.groupby(['id'])[df.filter(like='val').columns.tolist()].diff(-1).dropna()]).reset_index()
```

---

```
   id  val1  val2  val3
0   1  -0.4  -0.2  -3.1
1   2   0.1  -0.2  17.0
2   3  -0.1  -0.8   1.5
```

I have added an extra valX just for illustration purposes.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know `diff(-1)` and it is indeed useful. Nevertheless I am already using `pd.concat(...)` and is one of the parts I want to avoid :)

Comment: Welcome! Glad your question was answered. Indeed sammywemmy's approach would be the one to go in my opinion too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot the dataframe:

```
x = df.pivot(index="id", columns="type", values="val1")
y = df.pivot(index="id", columns="type", values="val2")

df = pd.concat([x["A"] - x["B"], y["A"] - y["B"]], axis=1).rename(
    columns={0: "val1", 1: "val2"}
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    val1  val2
id            
1   -0.4  -0.2
2    0.1  -0.2
3   -0.1  -0.8
```